# Place EditText on fix position on image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image background :
[image]

How can I place 2 `EditText` so in all sizes they will be on fixed place, for example on the two black boxes... When I used fixed position so in every resolution it looks different, I'm looking a way calculating it on runtime

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/background_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

   <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think this is hard to achieve if possible at all. Why don't you build this thing as a layout and use parts of your image as separate backgrounds?

Comment: @DrJerkberg  What do you mean? I have this image as it, I can only place my text over it, I don't have the option to use additional images

Comment: I believe your method of placing image on fixed position is wrong. Do you set `TextView` position using `.setX()` and `.setY()`?

Comment: Yes, I try to calculate the height,weight and by that to use setX/Y()

Comment: What I meant is you could cut your image into different parts, use those parts as backgrounds for views and then combine those views. That way you could make the layout resolution-independent by using 9-patch for the partial images.